# pglogical.replicate_ddl_command quote handling

Tags: postgresql, pglogical

Provider is on OEL 7 postgres 12.4 and Subscriber in on RDS 13.2

pglogical.replicate_ddl_command works fine as long as there are no quotes between start and end of the command.
for example, below works fine

```
select pglogical.replicate_ddl_command('create table public.foo ( like public.orders including all)','{default}'::text[]);
```

Event triggers are setup to add this newly created table to default replication_set.

Next, we need to attach table foo as a partition to table orders, and that's where quotes in FOR VALUES become a problem.

```
select pglogical.replicate_ddl_command('Alter table public.orders attach partition public.foo for values from ('2021-05-01') TO ('2021-06-01')','{default}'::text[]);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "2021"
LINE 1: ...ers attach partition public.foo for values from ('2021-05-01...
 
                                                          ^
```

Could not find anything in docs related to this.
please help.

Answer (score 0):

while I was able to get away with the error by using double quotes `''`, as the `command` argument on the function is text, the `ATTACH PARTITION` did not replicate. Although that is a separate issue than what I asked in this question, appreciate any feedback and ideas.

Leaving this note for anyone else who runs into my situation. The requirement is you need to add both parent and all its partitions to the same replication set. In my case I had all the partitions added but not the parent.